# Strange behavior splitting arrays with Ruby (v1.9.2)

Tags: ruby, arrays, split

I am trying to handle an array with Ruby v1.9.2 but it has some strange behavior.

The best explanation may be done with examples:

---

*CASE 1 TEST*

```
@test1 = "image/bmp, image/gif, image/jpg".split(',')
```

Debug @test1:

```
--- 
- image/bmp    # why this?!
- " image/gif"
- " image/jpg"
```

---

*CASE 2 TEST*

```
@test2 = ", image/bmp, image/gif, image/jpg".split(',')
```

Debug @test2:

```
--- 
- ""           # why this?!
- " image/bmp"
- " image/gif"
- " image/jpg"
```

---

**WHAT I NEED**

Notice: I can use the CASE 2 TEST, but I would like to do things right and better.

Debug that I would like to have:

```
--- 
- " image/bmp"
- " image/gif"
- " image/jpg"
```

Comment: That's not ruby-on-rails

Comment: why would you want a heading space on the resulting MIME types? @test1.split(',').map(&:strip) should be enough. Also don't use "debug" to show your results in the question, p is better here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the test case 1 there is no space before "image/bmp" in the result because there is no space before "image/bmp" in the original string.

In the test case 2 there is an empty string at the beginning because the string starts with a comma, and for every separator in the string there is a string in the resulting array, containing what comes before that separator (which in this case means the empty string).

If you want the result you've shown, you could just add a space (but no comma) before "image/bmp" in the source string. Alternatively you could split by `/, */` and then add one space before each string with map. Though frankly I don't get why you want a space before each string.

Comment: @user: Use my last suggestion (split on `/, */`) and *don't* add spaces afterwards.

Comment: Just doing: "image/bmp,image/gif,image/jpg" instead of "image/bmp, image/gif, image/jpg"

Answer (score 1):

```
>> ", image/bmp, image/gif, image/jpg".split(/\s*,\s*/).select{|x| x!=""}
=> ["image/bmp", "image/gif", "image/jpg"]
```